# Secret variables in HTML

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I Have a problem with nuxt3 and secret variables, I don't know why, I see the secret API URL in the site code. In my `nuxt.config.ts` I have the following:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  routeRules: {},
  modules: [],
  runtimeConfig: {
    app: {
      apiUrl: process.env.NUXT_API_HOST,
    },
  }
})
```

and at the code, I see:

```js
window.__NUXT__={};window.__NUXT__.config={public:{},app:{baseURL:"/",buildAssetsDir:"/_nuxt/",cdnURL:"",apiUrl:"https://api.nuxtjs.dev"}}
```

Any idea how to resolve the problem and hide that `apiUrl`?

Comment: Why is the API URL secret?!

Comment: It's an internal connection for the data

Comment: Give a look at this one: https://youtu.be/2tKOZc3Z1dk

Answer (score 1):

Your `runtimeConfig` should be like this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // hidden runtimeConfigs, available only server
    apiUrl: process.env.NUXT_API_HOST,
    public: {
      // public runtimeConfigs, available both server and client
    },
  }
})
```

[as indicated in the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#exposing-runtime-config)